# CRS and Spatial join problem

Tags: qgis, vector, dem, spatial-join

I try to match two layers. First one is point-type with cities in Europe. Second one is grid layer (polygon) with elevation value. What I want to achieve is to to join the "Z" value from grid layer to point layer.
Both have the same CRS and the result is very strange.
[image: This is what I see when I add two layers]

I was trying to set different CRS for these layers but the result is still the same.
[image]

Only two "Z" values occurs in created layer.

Probably something is wrong with elevation data but I don't have any idea to solve it.
Here I attached these two layers
http://www.speedyshare.com/GVUqM/DEM.zip

Comment: Rather - why grid layer is so 'distorted' ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your city coordinates are likely to be in WGS84 EPSG:4326.

But the DEM grid is not, and `Set CRS for Layer` is the wrong tool to change the CRS. Use `Save As ...` to a different filename and CRS.

But you first have to now which CRS the DEM data is actually in.

If you can't ask the data provider of the DEM about the source projection, take the data from http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/world-digital-elevation-model-etopo5 and proceed with that.

Comment: I was trying in many ways to change CRS and set them to WGS84 EPSG:4326.